# How do I pass a variable as an array separated by comma?

Tags: php, arrays, implode

A user enters two date periods on a text box and a message to be sent. I get the values as $time1 and $time2 and $message respectively. I use $time1 and $time2 in a select statement which should fetch the mobile numbers in the database between the two times. These are the numbers to receive the message.

Question, how do I save these numbers into one variable assuming they were ten numbers which I should pass to a web service to receive the message. The numbers also need to be separated by a comma to differentiate them. For separation, I think implode function would work in array. 
I am new in PHP so someone help me achieve this.  Thank you.

```
$message =mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['message']);
$time1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $t1);
$time2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $t2);

$sql =  "SELECT DISTINCT msisdn FROM customer WHERE DATE_FORMAT(time_paid, '%Y-%c-%e') BETWEEN ADDDATE('$time1',INTERVAL 0 HOUR) AND ADDDATE('$time2',INTERVAL '23:59' HOUR_MINUTE)";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) 
{
     //Output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
    {
    $mobilenumber = $row['msisdn'];
    }
} 
else 
{
  echo "No data in the server! ";
}
$conn->close();

sendbulk($mobilenumber, $message);

function sendbulk($mobilenumber, $message) 
{

    $serviceArguments = array(
        "mobilenumber" => $mobilenumber,
        "message" => $message
    );

   $client = new SoapClient("http://*****:8080/WebSms/smswebservice?wsdl");

    $result = $client->process($serviceArguments);

    return $result;
}
```

Comment: Start by not overwriting the numbers you get from the database `$mobilenumber = $row['msisdn'];` should be `$mobilenumber[] = $row['msisdn'];` Now you will have an array not just ONE NUMBER

Comment: Or if you only ever get one result, remove the while loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as @RiggsFolly said, currently you're overwriting the numbers coming from database. add them as he said, then, if you want it in just one variable as comma-separated, you could use **[implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)**

```
$mob_numbers = implode(", " , $mobilenumbers);
```

Comment: @user6664057 Glad to help